# how to sync the android sqlite table to MYSQL DB server?

Tags: android, sqlite, synchronization

How to sync my sqlite table with mysql server table in android? 
 Are there any library classes in android to sync the local db with server db? Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to use web service. Through that you can add/update/delete your data and sync with local and mysql server.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think there are any out of box classes available.
You might want to look at Sybase's solution
http://www.sybase.com/products/databasemanagement/sqlanywhere